# cannot find proper code for my actionbar

Tags: android

i have been looking at several examples with the action bar/menu bars. but my tablet is different, at the bottom there is the back button, home, recent, three dots.....

i cannot use menu bar at the top since my app is full screen surface view that refreshes over it

i cant figure out which code is for the three dots....at the bottom left corner

http://cdn.liliputing.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/apps.jpg

can someone point it out pls?

Answer (score 0):

The button you are seeing is the legacy menu button. It is shown for apps targeting API versions 10 and below. Specifically:

> - If you set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to 11 or higher,
>     the system will not add the legacy overflow button.
> - Otherwise, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running
>     on Android 3.0 or higher.
> - The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower,
>     set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar,
>     the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app
>     on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

For more information, read [Say Goodbye to the Menu Button](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).

Without some sample code, there isn't much more we can do to help diagnose your problem.

Comment: omg, i cant believe it was that easy, just turn the ver down, and poof there it was , thnx!